# send form data with files along with dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, dropzone.js

I have uploaded the file to s3 bucket using dropzonejs.

Now I need the normal post on submit button too.
but form_post doesn't contains $_FILES.

dropzone code: ----

```
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", { 
    url: '<?php echo base_url('app/attachments')?>',
    maxFiles:1,
    method:'post',
    paramName:'attachment',
    uploadMultiple:false,
    addRemoveLinks:true,
    params:{pg_tn:$('#pg_tn').val()},        
    acceptedFiles:".csv,.xls,.xlsx",
    //acceptedFiles:"image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,application/msword,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
    autoProcessQueue:true,
    maxFilesize:25,
    timeout:120000
  });
  myDropzone.on("success", function(file,response) {
   var res=JSON.parse(response);   
   console.log(res);
   $('#attachment_id').val(res.attachment_id);
  });
  myDropzone.on("removedfile",function(file){
      $('#attachment_id').val('');
  });
```

form_post code :--

```
var form = $('#ecommerce_frm')[0];
var data = new FormData(form);
$("#btnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "<?php echo base_url('ecommerce/uploadsalesheet');?>",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (e) {

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Dropzone POSTs your files immediately, unless you configure it not to.  Once they are successfully POSTed, they are considered processed and done, and so removed from the form.

If you want to POST them with your other form data, the best option is probably to disable automatic processing, so that the files are not POSTed until you submit your form.  Note this means that files and form values are POSTed to the same URL, the same handler.  You will have to combine your `ecommerce/uploadsalesheet` and `app/attachments` methods into a single method, to handle a POST including files and data.

To do that, first disable auto processing in your Dropzone options:

```
autoProcessQueue = false,
```

Then, manually process your files when you click your button.  Your code doesn't show it but I guess the `$.ajax()` code you'e shown is wrapped in a `$("#btnSubmit").on('click', function() {...})`, or similar, so inside that handler, do:

```
myDropzone.processQueue();
```

You should also remove all the `$.ajax()` code too now, since Dropzone is now doing the POST and you don't need to.  You'll have to move any specific success or failure handling into [Dropzone's appropriate event handlers](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list).

The next problem is that none of your other form fields are sent with the files, since Dropzone doesn't know about them.  I think the `params` option can do that, something like:

```
params: $('#ecommerce_frm').serialize(),
```

I haven't tried using `params` before, but if it does not work, this does - you can append the form values manually, using Dropzone's `sending` callback:

```
myDropzone.on('sending', function(file, xhr, formData) {
    // Append all form inputs to the formData Dropzone will POST
    var data = $('#ecommerce_frm').serializeArray();
    $.each(data, function(key, el) {
        formData.append(el.name, el.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have only one ajax call on button click to resend form-data to different url .
and problem is form-data doesn't contains the $_FILES.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan Yes, your button click currently does an AJAX call.  Dropzone does another AJAX POST (happens before your AJAX call). My answer describes how to combine them into 1 POST.

Comment: My requirement doesn't allow to combine them, i know how dropzonejs works.May be I couldn't describe my requirement.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan Your question says you want the `$_FILES` with the normal POST ... that means everything in 1 post, right?  If that's not correct, can you edit your question and try to explain it better?

Comment: Actually after uploading files with Dropzonejs.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan That's not what you asked for - `but form_post doesn't contains $_FILES.` Maybe you should edit your question to match what you really want.